# GoogleAdMob Plugin Unity. Resolving Android Dependencies. InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I am using Unity 2018.3.0f2 and in the process of installing the Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.15.1, an empty cmd prompt shows up a few times and the Resolving Android Dependencies Windows shows up, freezes and the error

```
InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected. 
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput () (at <3845a180c26b4889bc2d47593a665814>:0)
```

shows up in the console.

I've looked up methods to solve this but none of them mentions this StandardIn at all.

This is the full error that shows:

```
InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected.
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput () (at <3845a180c26b4889bc2d47593a665814>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput()
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler, System.Boolean useShellExecution, System.Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode) (at <0ea28fee5338451fbecc93319b91e068>:0)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.Run (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler) (at <0ea28fee5338451fbecc93319b91e068>:0)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () (at <0ea28fee5338451fbecc93319b91e068>:0)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
UnityEngine.UnhandledExceptionHandler:<RegisterUECatcher>m__0(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may sound kinda weird, but I've fixed by removing any punctuation mark from my Unity Project Folder Name, in my case it was an apostrophe.

Also make sure you've set paths to jdk, jre, and JAVA_HOME.

Hope it helps!